# List objects from publicly accessible Amazon S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-ruby

I have one Amazon S3 bucket which is public with list and get permission. I want to list object in  ruby. We can use AWS SDK to list objects but it require credentials. I want to list objects in ruby without using credentials. how to achieve this ??

Answer (score 0):

To use **AWS SDK** in any language, you need to create a **Service Client** in that given language, Ruby is no different from .NET, Python, Java, etc.

To make an AWS Service call from a **Service Client** (not CLI, or Rest, etc), you must specify creds. More information can be found in the AWS Ruby DEV Guide:

[Configuring the AWS SDK for Ruby](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v3/developer-guide/setup-config.html)

Comment: Actually, `boto3` has the ability to make an unsigned API call, which enables the AWS CLI to use `--no-sign-request`, so AWS credentials are not required. See: [Equivalent of aws s3 cp with --no-sign-request for boto3.client() ? · Issue #1200 · boto/boto3 · GitHub](https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/1200)

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use the HTTP Method.Amazon S3 support make requests to Amazon S3 endpoints by using the REST API.
I try putObject with HTTP Method and it work,I use the curl command.
But the Object owner is anonymous, i can't remove it.
And I am not familiar with Ruby,I think it also work with listObject without use SDK.

This is my curl command :
curl --request PUT --upload-file "./myobject" "https://${mybkt}......../myobject"

ListObject HTTP method Doc:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_ListObjectsV2.html

Answer (score 0):

Not all AWS SDKs expose options to make unsigned API requests. There is no option in the Ruby SDK.

You might want to comment on, or re-open, this previously-closed [feature request](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby/issues/1149) in the Ruby SDK.